# Nested Divs Spacing

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div and two nested divs.  I have the nested divs set as `display: table-cell`.  How can you set spacing between those nested divs?  I've tried `margin`, but that didn't do anything (the jsFiddle has `margin` set, yet with no effect).

[jsFiddle showing my question/problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Surfer/cZptA/4/)

Comment: Are you setting them to `table-cell` for any particular reason?

Comment: @BlackWraith Good question.  Yes, I am setting them like this so they can be side by side without having to use `float` on them (float is hurting the other divs in the parent).

Comment: Fair enough. Something you can do is put them in an empty div with no class settings or the such, and then float them inside that?

Comment: I'd float them, but if you're really set on `table-cell`, adding a border is kinda hacky but seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/cZptA/19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `display: inline-table;` instead of `display: table-cell`. Write like this

```
.child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cZptA/9/

Comment: That causes the divs to stack instead of being side by side.

Comment: There is no need to do this, it is possible the same way OP wants. See my question

Answer (score 2):

This should fix you’re issue. I assume your looking to get a checkerboard effect?

```
.child {
      float:left;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: table-cell`, try this:

```
.child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### It is possible and very simple

Since you have specified the child divs to behave as table-cell, by default they will be no spacing between them just like a regular table. **So, there is nothing wrong with you code.**

If you really want your `divs` to behave as tables. Your parent div should have `border-spacing` for the spacing between the `table-cells`.

```
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/cZptA/12/)

Comment: Not possible to add just left `border-spacing` though.

Comment: @steveax, It is possible to give top/bottom & left/right spacing like `border-spacing: 20px 50xp;`